# adding string numbers (math) with local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add numbers as strings using basic math. I first set the local storage to "0" then add "1" to it each time. I feel I am on the right path, but when I run this my result is not 0 + 1 = 1 rather I get "01" in my local storage. I want to be able to add 1 to the existing local storage each time so 0 + 1 I get 1. Next time around 1 + 1 I get 2, and 2 + 1 I get 3 and so on.

```
// sets "points" to 0 when user first loads page.
if (localStorage.getItem("points") === null){
localStorage.setItem("points", "0");
}

// get points
var totalPoints = localStorage.getItem("points");
// add 1 points to exisiting total
var addPoint = totalPoints +"1";
// set new total
localStorage.setItem("points", addPoint);
```

Comment: @Pointy localstorage only takes a string

Comment: Yes I figured that out :-)  Sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string to a number in several ways (not an exhaustive list):

```
var n = s * 1; // s is the string
var n = s - 0;
var n = parseFloat(s);
var n = Number(s);
var n = ~~s; // force to 32-bit integer
var n = parseInt(s, 10); // also integer, precise up to 53 bits
```

Convert your strings to numbers when you fetch them from local storage, do the math, and then put the results back.

*edit* — the thing to keep in mind is that `+` is more "interesting" than the other arithmetic operators because it has meaning for string-valued operands. In fact, JavaScript tends to *prefer* string interpretation of the `+` operator, so if there's a string on one side and a number on the other, the operation is string concatenation and not arithmetic addition.

Comment: @Mageek The ~ operator is the bitwise negation operator. Applying it once to a string forces it to be interpreted as a number (an integer), and the result is the "one's complement" of that value. Using two of the operators gives you back the original integer value.

Comment: @Mageek yes I think that should work; I extended the answer a little. The parentheses are important!

Comment: You should not present `parseInt` and `~~` as the same thing, `~~` maxes out at `+2147483647` and mins out at `-2147483648`, whereas `parseInt` can do `9007199254740992/-9007199254740992` and even after that it just loses precision.

Comment: Yes that's true, @Esailija - they're quite different.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage.getItem("points") === null){
  localStorage.setItem("points", 0);
}
//Get points
var totalPoints = Number(localStorage.getItem("points"));
//Add 1 points to the existing total
var addPoint = totalPoints + 1;
//Set new total
localStorage.setItem("points", addPoint);
console.log(addPoint);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).